# Ubuntu Issues on HP Pavilion Slimline s3713w

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, hp

This is my grandfather's [PC specifications](http://support.hp.com/us-en/product/HP-Pavilion-Slimline-s3000-Desktop-PC-series/3824206/model/3870525/document/c01623239/) and I'm trying to get any version of Linux to work on it.

I like Ubuntu the most, cause I can customize it to only give him what he needs.  It tries to boot to the desktop and then locks up when using 12.04 and 14.04. If I run in low end graphics mode it works but is super slow.

It's using the Geforce 6150SE integrated graphics and if I install that nVidia drive it comes up with a black screen and my mouse cursor but nothing else. I have performed update and upgrade and still no luck.

What am I missing?, how can I get this to work?- I'm willing to use any version of Linux to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try 13.10 I am currently having this same issue. Also try installing the graphics card version as is on the nvidia website.

My HP Pavilion is a laptop mind you

Comment: I also downloaded 10.04 but have not been able to test it yet.  I'm going back over there today to try both of these.  It looks like the right driver I need is nvidia-173.  I'll test and report back.